# Opengl proper lighting problem

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, lighting

I have written the following program to display a teapot on a table in a room with 2side walls and a floor.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glut.h>


void wall1(float thickness)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(100,100,0);
    glRotatef(90,1,0,0);
    glScalef(thickness,1,1);
    glutSolidCube(100);
    glPopMatrix();
}
void wall2(float thickness)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(150,100,-50);
    glScalef(1,1,thickness);
    glutSolidCube(100);
    glPopMatrix();
}
void floor(float thickness)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(150,50,0);
    glScalef(1,thickness,1);
    glutSolidCube(100);
    glPopMatrix();
}
void leg(float thickness)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glScalef(thickness,.5,thickness);
    glutSolidCube(100);
    glPopMatrix();
}
void tableTop(float thickess)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(150,100,0);
    glScalef(.5,thickess,.5);
    glutSolidCube(100);
    glPopMatrix();
}
void table()
{
    tableTop(.05);

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(125,75,-25);
    leg(.05);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(175,75,-25);
    leg(.05);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(175,75,25);
    leg(.05);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(125,75,25);
    leg(.05);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(150,110,0);
    glScalef(.1,.1,.1);
    glutSolidTeapot(100);
    glPopMatrix();
}
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    float pos[] = {200,200,0};
    float dif[] = {.3,.3,.3,3};
    float spe[] = {1,1,1,1};
    float amb[] = {1,1,1,0};
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_POSITION,pos);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_DIFFUSE,dif);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_AMBIENT,amb);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_SPECULAR,spe);

    glTranslatef(50,50,0);
    glRotatef(30,1,0,0);
    glRotatef(-30,0,1,0);
    wall1(.05);
    wall2(.05);
    floor(0.05);
    table();

    glFlush();
}
void reshape(int w,int h)
{
    glViewport(0,0,w,h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0,400,0,400,-400,400);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(400,400);
    glutCreateWindow("woot");
    glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);


    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

The problem with this is my lighting part is not working as expected. Its not illuminating **evenly** all my objects... What am i missing? This making even the teapot hard to sea.
My lighting part is in display function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was missing

> glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);

in the main function, and thus opengl was not rendering it properly! Alse @Christian's answer of using ambient only worked.

:)

Comment: But you know, that ambient is no light but a consant color?

Comment: Ah, I see what happened right now: Scaling also affects the normals. Also try glEnable(GL_RESCALE_NORMAL); if it's available it's a little bit faster than normalizing.

Comment: @christian oh! i didnt know that.. though it was a light source... It will be added to the acual material color right

Comment: The light's ambient color is multiplied by the meterial's ambient color. But as it doesn't take any normals or other things into account, it is just a constant color without any impression of space.

Answer (score 3):

OpenGL fixed function pipeline lighting is evaluated at the vertices only. `glutSolidCube` just creates vertices at the corners and nowhere else. So your lighting is calculated only very coarse. You could either switch to per fragment lighting by using a shader, or tesselate your objects. The latter requires you don't use `glutSolidCube` and instead load objects modelled in a 3D modeller or write your own primitive generators that offer a higher tesselation. I strongly recommend the first option.

`glutSolidCube` is just a very crude stand in function BTW.

Comment: ok :) This is just for practice with lighting functions i am writing the program for. I will keep that in mind the next time i write program

Answer (score 0):

If you want to evenly light all objects, only use ambient lighting.